# How to use wait(); in a process in order to wait for its child processed to be executed first

Tags: c, linux, parent-child, pid

every `printf` command represents a process. `p0` process should wait for `p2` process to get executed while `p2` should wait for at least 2 of its children (`p3,p4,p5`) to be executed first :

````
```
    #include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#define _POSIX_SOURCE
int main()
{
    int pid1, pid2, pid3, pid4, pid5;
    int i;
    int status;

    pid1=fork();

    if (pid1 != 0){
      wait(&status);
    printf("I'm the parent P0.PID=%d, PPID=%d.\n", getpid(), getppid());}
else{

     printf("I'm the child P1 my parent is P0. PID=%d, PPID=%d.\n", getpid(), getppid());


    pid2=fork();

    if (pid2!=0){

    printf("I'm the child P2 and parent to p3,p4,p5.PID=%d, PPID=%d.\n", getpid(), getppid());



    pid3=fork();
    if (pid3 == 0){
    printf("I'm the child P3.PID=%d, PPID=%d.\n", getpid(), getppid());
}
    else {

        pid4=fork();
        if(pid4 == 0)
        {
    printf("I'm the child P4.PID=%d, PPID=%d.\n", getpid(), getppid());
}  else{
            pid5 = fork();
            if(pid5 == 0)
        {
    printf("I'm the child P5.PID=%d, PPID=%d.\n", getpid(), getppid());
              }
           }
        }
     }
  }
    /*  
    if(getppid(&pid1)==getppid(&pid5)){

        execl("/bin/ps","ps","-f",(char *)NULL);
    }*/
return 0;
  }

              P0
           /      \  
         P1        P2
                 / | \
                P3 P4 P5
````

Comment: P0 is calling `wait()` before it forks P2. It's only waiting for P1.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Hello im just so new to stack overflow (i dont even know the basics).Thanks again for helping me out.

Comment: You need to add an `else` block in `if(pid5==0)` that calls `wait()` in a loop to wait for 2 of the children.

Comment: @barmar thanks, i'm just so bad, at least i' m trying.

Comment: @Barmar i cant put an else into an if {} just because if should be close "}" before using else statement. but apart from that it seems like everytime im using wait it does nothing, like at all.

Comment: its the same as if i used it after "if" statement and not essentially into it but anyways it doesnt work i might be doing something wrong.

Comment: Be aware that if output is not to a tty (eg, if you run this program with output redirected to a file), you will see some behavior that you may consider odd (lines being printed multiple times).

Answer (score 0):

In the first place, use a brace-enclosed block for the `else` associated with "`if (pid4==0)`", and be sure to nest the "`if (pid5==0)`" block inside.  That gives you better internal consistency, but more importantly, it avoids testing the value of `pid5` in a process that never sets it:

```
                else {
                    pid5=fork();
                    if (pid5==0){
                        printf("I'm the child P5.PID=%d, PPID=%d.\n", getpid(), getppid()); 
                    }
                }
```

Then, if you add an `else` block to that innermost nested `if`, it will be entered only by process 2.  In such a block, then, you can insert two calls to `wait()` to collect two children.

Note also that the `wait()` immediately following `if (pid!=0){` appears to be misplaced.  It is called by **p0** at a time when **p1** is the only child it has forked.  It will therefore cause **p0** to wait for ***p1***, whereas your stated intention is to wait for **p2**, which hasn't yet been forked at that point.  You have expressed no requirement to wait on **p1** at all.  The wait for `p2` could go in an `else` block associated with `if (pid2==0)`.

Note also, however, that since it wants to wait for **p2** specifically, **p0** must avoid being fooled in the likely event that it collects **p1** first.  You can get it right by checking the return value of `wait()` (which on success is the pid of the child collected), or you can use `waitpid()` instead, to wait specifically on process **p2** and no other.

Comment: thanks you helped a lot, i fixed the p0 parent process so it will be executed after p2, but i think p2 should be executed after at least 2 of its children (p3,p4,p5) get executed first (can't do that).  Shouldn't the new output be : p3,p4,p5 or 2 of those, then p2 then p0? Can i achieve that? i will post the new code above. Also i tried adding 2 wait() commands after--> if (pid3==0) and if (pid4==0) but it didn't work i think 1 or more wait commands should be placed at pid2==0 so that p2 would wait for its children (not sure thought).

Comment: @rnduser21, if process **p2** starts some children and then waits for them, then it runs both before *and* after they do.  I have already answered how you should set that up.  To make it perform its printing only after the waited-for children do, put its `printf()` call after its `wait()` calls (in code that only that process runs).

Comment: pidwait does absolutely nothing.Apart from that removing misplaced wait after p1 means that p1 will be executed prior to p2 no matter what else i try(including adding to the else block associated with pid2). Also by adding 2 wait(); calls after printf i didnt achieve anything.